# Facebook api - friends status updates

Tags: facebook, api

Very early in designing a concept and I was wondering whether it is possible using fb api to get a friends history of status updates? Or even a status update from a particular date in the past?

Hunting the documentation I am yet to see anything such as this so appreciate any guidance!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In addition to OffBySome's answer, you could use [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/), or more specifically, the [`stream` table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/). This will let you query by dates, and filter more specifically, provided you have enough conditions to make the query indexable.

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/friendID/statuses will provide you with all of a friends statuses. You can set limit querystring parameter to get more, and use "prev" and "next" elements to navigate back and forth.  Try exploring on the [Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).